# Using grep or find to get all files created in 2018 with "log" extension

Tags: playonlinux, grep, find

Directory contains catalogs that have the following format: «20180201».

I want to Get the list of all files created in 2018 with the "log" extension and their sizes.

Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: Is it another school task?

Answer (score 2):

The `«20180201»` format doesn't seem to be relevant to this task - unless you are being asked to use the name of the file rather than filesystem metadata to determine its age.

If you want to find files by their actual age (modification time), you can use the `find` command, ex.:

```
find /var/log -newermt 2018-01-01 ! -newermt 2019-01-01 -name '*.log' -exec du -h {} +
```

Replace `/var/log` with the starting directory in which you wish to search.

From `man find`:

> ```
>    -newerXY reference
>           Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being  considered  is  newer
>           than  timestamp  Y  of the file reference.   The letters X and Y
>           can be any of the following letters:
>
>           a   The access time of the file reference
>           B   The birth time of the file reference
>           c   The inode status change time of reference
>           m   The modification time of the file reference
>           t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Very good simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very nice solution, but hope it could help somehow.

```
for l in "$(ls -ailh $(find 2018folder/* -iname "*.log" | grep 20180201))"
do echo "$l\n" | \
     sed -n 's/  */ /gp' | \
     cut -d" " -f6,10-14 | \
     sed -n 's/ /\t/gp'
done
```

- `find 2018folder/* -iname "*.log"` will find all `.log` files in `2018folder` which should contain your `20180201` like folders
- `ls -ailh` will show their sizes with other unneeded information
- `sed -n 's/  */ /gp'` will remove double spaces
- `cut -d" " -f6,10-14` will leave only sizes and paths to files
- `sed -n 's/ /\t/gp'` will replace spaces by tabs for better look.

If you need only files sizes and their names without paths:

```
for l in "$(ls -ailh $(find 2018folder/* -iname "*.log" | grep 20180201))";
do echo "$l\n" | \
   sed -n 's/  */ /gp' | \
   cut -d" " -f6,10-14 | \
   sed -n 's/ /\t/gp' | \
   cut -d/ -f1,3 | \         # leave only 1st and 3rd columns using `/` as delimiter
   sed 's/2018folder\///';   # remove `2018folder/` from output
done
```